# How can I implement ImageJ API in my Java code?

Tags: java, image-processing, imagej

I need to use ImageJ API for java, but I don't know where to look for the proper .jar .
I looked [here](http://maven.imagej.net/index.html#nexus-search;gav~net.imagej~imagej~~~~kw,versionexpand) but non of those appear to be the right one to implement (they don't have the classes shown in the documentation)

Comment: You're most likely looking for http://rsbweb.nih.gov/ij/download.html (although, admittedly, I'm also a bit confused about these libraries right now...)

Comment: Thank you, this made me go back and take another look at that page. the proper .jar appears when you click the "online" link in the section "Source Code"

Comment: The site http://imagej.net/ is the unified website about ImageJ. The [source code page](http://imagej.net/Source_code) and other [development topics](http://imagej.net/Development) explain the structure of the libraries. If it is still confusing, suggestions on improving the documentation would be most welcome. The site is a wiki so anyone can make edits and improvements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library `net.imagej:imagej` is the toplevel [ImageJ2](http://imagej.net/ImageJ2) library.

The library `net.imagej:ij` is the library for [ImageJ 1.x](http://imagej.net/ImageJ1).

You can add a dependency on ImageJ 1.x to your application using the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.imagej</groupId>
    <artifactId>ij</artifactId>
    <version>1.49m</version>
</dependency>
```

You can also:

- [Browse the available versions on Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.imagej%22%20AND%20a%3A%22ij%22)
- [Access older versions from the ImageJ Maven repository](http://maven.imagej.net/index.html#nexus-search;gav~net.imagej~ij~~~~kw,versionexpand)
- See the [ImageJ Maven primer](http://imagej.net/Maven) if you are new to Maven

Answer (score 0):

I just found the right .jar with some push given by Marco13's comment. You can find it [here](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/source/), is called ***ij.jar***

Comment: Note that downloading ij.jar from this site will be an arbitrary version (whatever the latest IJ version is). Using a Maven dependency as suggested by ctrueden above provides the same classes, with precise version coupling - and is thus the preferred way of developing if you're going to want to distribute your plugin to others. See also [Reproducible Build](http://imagej.net/Reproducible_builds#Reproducible_builds) documentation.